# Problem with array in javascript. dont print value

Tags: javascript, django

I am working in django 1.11 and want to export data to javascript, right now it works!. But I have a problem that at the moment when I print the array it isn't an array cause it prints character by character

I want to have something like that:

Color_rgb = [ 160.73776956820626, 192.43254103235958, 58.88702020483803]

when i write:
 Color_rgb[0];
my output should be:
 160.73776956820626

views.py

```py
def vista(request):
    Color_RGB = []
    semana_max = Resultados_Alumnos.objects.all().aggregate(Max('noSemana'))
    Resultados_RGB= []
    for Color in Resultados_Alumnos.objects.raw('Select * from test_app_alumno_competencia_evaluacion_estado where idMapasxalumnos_id = 25 and noSemana = %s',[semana_max["noSemana__max"]]):
        R = Color.bajo * 0
        G = Color.medio * 1
        B = Color.alto * 2
        RGB = R + G + B     
        Incertidumbre = (-Color.bajo * ln(Color.bajo)  - Color.medio * ln(Color.medio) - Color.alto * ln(Color.alto)) / -ln(1.0/3) 
        B = Incertidumbre * 60
        if RGB >= 1:
            R = int((2 - RGB) * 255) 
            G = 255
        else:
            G = int((1 - RGB) * 255) 
            R = 255 

        R = R - Incertidumbre * R *.25
        G = G - Incertidumbre * G *.25
        Resultados_RGB = [R, G , B]
        Color_RGB.append(Resultados_RGB)

    context = { 'color': Color_RGB }
    return render(request, 'resultados_app/resultados.html', context )
```

html

```html
<script>
    var rgb = []
    '{% for k in color %}'
        rgb.push('{{ k }}');
    '{% endfor %}'
</script>
```

my bad javascript

```
var Array_rgb = []
    for (let colores = 0; colores < rgb.length; colores++) {
      var color = rgb[colores];
      Array_rgb.push(color);

    }

    for (let colores = 0; colores < Array_rgb.length; colores++) {
      var Color_rgb = Array_rgb[colores];
      alert(Color_rgb[0]);
    }
```

when I tried them my output is: "["

Help! please!!

Answer (score 0):

Your output is `[` cause you showing the output of `index:0` of a string only. Here the javascript code will work correctly.

```
<script>

        var rgb='{{color}}'; 
        //now rgb is a string.
        //so the first character [ and last character ] removed 
        rgb=rgb.substr(1,rgb.length-2);
        rgb=rgb.split(', ');
        alert(rgb[0]);
        rgb.forEach(el => {
            console.log(el);
        });

    </script>
```